# iPhone, how does one read an image from the UIPasteboard as NSData?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, nsdata, uipasteboard

I have an image that I append a message to inside the NSData of the image and then save it to the photo library using ALAssetLibrary. I then send it to someone over email.

I want to give the user the option to press and hold a modified image and then press copy and paste it in my app. To do this my app would have to read the image that was copied either byte by byte to get the whole file (preferred method) or read the whole thing as an NSData.

How would I be able to read the general pasteboard's contents as NSData or byte for byte on a buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the documentation for [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)? The first thing that jumps out at me is:

```
- (NSData *)dataForPasteboardType:(NSString *)pasteboardType
```

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to have worked. I was able to get the data of the image exactly, which is good cause it kept the modifications. The only issue left is I have no way of telling what the pasteboard type would be, either public.jpg or public.png. I'm not sure how to look into the pasteboard to see how I can find out what kind of image it is so I know what to call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below code to read the image data from UIPasteboard .

```
UIPasteboard * pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom" create:YES];
NSData *data = [pasteBoard dataForPasteboardType:@"com.appshop.copyfrom.imagedata"];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

for more check blog posts.

[How to Use UIPasteBoard to Implement Custom Copy and Paste In Your App](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43447/How-to-Use-UIPasteBoard-to-Implement-Custom-Copy-a/?display=Mobile)

Comment: That would only work though if I was using the original copy in my app. I want to be able to copy from the apple Mail app and load it into mine. I believe that uses general pasteboard.